# Prepared statement - cross table update

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I am attempting to use a prepared statement in combination with a cross table update. I have prepared a sample script that is representative of our larger database. This first section does what I want without a prepared statement, but I am hoping to avoid copy/pasting this for every column of my data.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000000;
drop table if exists update_test;
create table update_test(
time_index decimal(12,4),
a varchar(20),
b varchar(20),
c varchar(20));
insert into update_test(time_index) values(20150101.0000),(20150101.0015),(20150101.0030);

drop table if exists energy_values;
create table energy_values(
time_stamp decimal(12,4),
site_id varchar(5),
energy int);
insert into energy_values 
values(20150101.0000,'a',100),(20150101.0000,'b',200),(20150101.0000,'c',300),
      (20150101.0015,'a',400),(20150101.0015,'b',500),(20150101.0015,'c',600),
      (20150101.0030,'a',700),(20150101.0030,'b',800),(20150101.0030,'c',900);

drop table if exists update_test_sites;
create table update_Test_sites(
sites varchar(5));
insert into update_test_sites values
('a'),('b'),('c');

update update_test, energy_values, update_test_sites
set    update_test.a=energy_values.energy
where update_test.time_index = energy_values.time_stamp
and energy_values.site_id ='a';

update update_test, energy_values, update_test_sites
set    update_test.b=energy_values.energy
where update_test.time_index = energy_values.time_stamp
and energy_values.site_id ='b';

update update_test, energy_values, update_test_sites
set    update_test.c=energy_values.energy
where update_test.time_index = energy_values.time_stamp
and energy_values.site_id ='c';
select * from update_test;
```

Which is why I have attempted something like this as a replacement for the update functions. However, I often get a syntax error report. Can anyone identify where I am going wrong? It would be much appreciated!

```
SELECT
concat(

'update update_test, energy_values, update_test_sites
set    update_test.',sites,'=energy_values.energy
where update_test.time_index = energy_values.time_stamp
and energy_values.site_id = ',sites,';
select * from update_test;')

from update_test_sites
where sites = 'a'
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen "SELECT INTO" work that way. In my experience, it is used like so:

```
SELECT [field_list] INTO [variable_list] 
FROM [some_table] 
[etc...]
```

I don't think it can be used to store a resultset like it appears you are attempting.

With some tweaking and doing this in a stored procedure, you could use a cursor to iterate over the results to prepare and execute each generated statement individually.